# Flask Iterating data in WTForms from a list with jinja2 to generate form fields

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying generate a checklist in a html table from a json file using `BooleanField()` So far I have it without using wtforms:

from view.py

```
from app import app

from flask import render_template

json_data = [{'Description':'Red', 'id':'f1'},{'Description':'Green', 'id':'f2'},{'Description':'Blue', 'id':'f3'}]


@app.route('/taggs', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def taggs()
    return render_template('taggs.html', jdata = json_data)
```

from taggs.html

```
<form role="form" method= "post">
<table id='ctable'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="Description"></th>
        <th data-field="Selection"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
    {% for i in jdata %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ i.Description }}</td>
        <td><input type ="checkbox" id = "{{ i.id }}"></td>
    </tr>
    {% end for%}
</table>
</form>
```

Is there a way of generating form fields using a list in wtforms? or do I have to create a class and declare each variable in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this dynamically in your view function.

[The docs](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.1/specific_problems.html) have an example of this, which you can adapt along the lines of:

```
from flask import render_template, request
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import BooleanField

json_data = [{'Description':'Red', 'id':'f1'}, 
             {'Description':'Green', 'id':'f2'}, 
             {'Description':'Blue', 'id':'f3'}]


@app.route('/taggs', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def taggs():
    class CustomForm(Form):
        pass

    for item in json_data:
        setattr(CustomForm, item["id"], 
                BooleanField(item["description"], id=item["id"]))

    form = CustomForm(request.form)

    return render_template('taggs.html', form=form)
```

Comment: @PJ_Santoro what do you put in the jinja 2 loop?

Comment: if you use Flask-Bootstrap you can use [the wtf.quick_form() macro](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/forms.html) or loop through the items `{% for element in form %}{{ element.label }}{{ element() }}...` like the [wtforms docs](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/1.0.1/crash_course.html#rendering-fields). mostly depends on your data model and how you'd like it to render.